# Sharepoint 2013 Rest API call to extract Excel specific cells

Tags: rest, sharepoint-2013

This should be pretty straight forward, just haven't been able to find any documentation, so unsure if it is possible, and if it is - how.

I'm calling the Sharepoint 2013 REST API, specifically the Excel REST services (ExcelRest.aspx), to fetch values from specific cells in an Excel workbook.

I've had success with the following two types of calls:

**Fetch one specific cell (E5):**
http://somesharepointsite.com/testsite/_vti_bin/ExcelRest.aspx/Shared%20Documents/Excelfile.xlsx/Model/Ranges('''Front%20page''!E5')?$format=html

**Fetch range (E5-F20):**
http://somesharepointsite.com/testsite/_vti_bin/ExcelRest.aspx/Shared%20Documents/Excelfile.xlsx/Model/Ranges('''Front%20page''!E5|F20')?$format=html

However I would very much like to be able to fetch multiple specific cells e.g: E5, E7, F15, F18.

This is due to how the information is placed in the spreadsheet, which isn't really convenient for automated extration. So instead of counting rows/columns to find relevant cells when extracting a range, it would much easier if all cells of relevance could be indicated directly.

I know I could just make a bunch of separate calls fetching one cell at the time, but that doesn't really seem like the optimum solution.

I've tried separating the range with commas, semicolons - also tried making two separate Ranges - no luck

Any suggestions are welcome

Comment: Did you solve this? Care to share? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, simplify the problem.  I would create a hidden sheet that puts all the relevant data in a single range that you can pull from and give it a Named Range.  Then call that Range.  These values are linked the the master sheet.  Hidden only in there's no reason to confuse anyone if they open up the spreadsheet.